# How to customize Alert Dialog button background and title divider from my theme xml file

Tags: android, customization, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I stuck for more than 2 full days, doing this. 
So far, I can change only the Title text color using style XML file. Other than that no attributes work well. Almost covered all STACK OVERFLOW questions, but not luck, not able to find answers.

Here's what I want to do:

[image]

(Delete button is focussed)

As of now, I am able to do this only by programmatically by getting titleDivider, Positive and Negative button and assigning background. But that said I hate to do this by programmatically.

Some one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use this project [AlertDialogPro](https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro).
Include this project to yours and define your theme like below:

```
<style name="YourAppTheme.AlertDialogProTheme" parent="AlertDialogProTheme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Custom the title style -->
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/YourDialogWindowTitle</item>
    <!-- Change the title divider to green -->
    <item name="adpTitleDividerBackground">@color/your_green_color</item>
    <!-- Change the button style -->
    <item name="adpButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/YourButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="YourDialogWindowTitle" parent="DialogWindowTitle.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_green_color</item>
</style>

<style name="YourButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Holo.Button.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_button_background_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_button_text_selector</item>
</style>
```

And specify this theme to your app's theme with attribute "alertDialogProTheme":

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  ...
  <item name="alertDialogProTheme">@style/YourAppTheme.AlertDialogProTheme</item>
</style>
```

Use AlertDialogPro.Builder to build dialog:

```
AlertDialogPro.Builder builder = new AlertDialogPro.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle("Delete").
    setMessage("Are you sure?").
    setPositiveButton("Delete", null).
    setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).
    show();
```

Comment: Actually I did not want to use any third party library. Even in the given library they used to change the theme programmatically not by xml. Sorry..

Comment: You can change the theme by xml as I wrote above.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I need to use inherit the AlertDialogPro project into my app right?  I don't wanna use any other project.

Comment: The android's api can allow you to change the theme of the AlertDialog's title and button. But there isn't a public api for you to change the divider's color. It would be very hard to resolve this problem if you don't use any other project.

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI This answers your question. Mark this as your answer.

Comment: @M.S. Thanks for your effort. I have done this without using a third party library. At run time, we can get the id of buttons and setting the background. That is the answer. Bit costlier, but Works at all. I already voted up your answer.